# Selecting text or shape fails: "enterEditMode" requires a selection

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, jsfl

I have the following (useless) code, which should select each text element in the current Flash document:

```
fl.outputPanel.clear();
var textFieldArray = fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", fl.getDocumentDOM());
fl.trace(textFieldArray.length);
for (var i=0; i < textFieldArray.length; i ++){
    fl.selectElement(textFieldArray[i]);
}
```

Surprisingly, this results in an error

> At line 232 of file "ObjectFindAndSelect.jsfl": 'enterEditMode' requires a selection.

Looking into the file, the code for the `selectElement` function is

```
flash.selectElement = function(elementData, editSymbol)
{
    if (elementData.parent != undefined)
    {
        // go up one level
        flash.selectElement(elementData.parent, true);
    }
    else
    {
        FlashUtils_debugString("flash.selectElement function: element is on the main timeline");
    }

    // select the layer, keyframe and element in the symbol instance
    var layerIndex = FlashUtils_getIndexOfObject(elementData.timeline.layers, elementData.layer);
    var frameIndex = FlashUtils_getIndexOfObject(elementData.layer.frames, elementData.keyframe);
    if ((layerIndex >= 0) && (frameIndex >= 0))
    {
        // go to obj keyframe
        elementData.timeline.setSelectedLayers(layerIndex);
        elementData.timeline.setSelectedFrames(frameIndex, frameIndex);

        // clear all selections in keyframe
        fl.getDocumentDOM().selectNone();

        // select the obj
        elementData.obj.selected = true;

        if (editSymbol)
        {
            // switch to editing the symbol item associated with instance
            document.enterEditMode('inPlace');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FlashUtils_debugString("flash.selectElement function: parent: failed to get valid layerIndex: " + layerIndex + " or frameIndex: " + frameIndex);
    }
}
```

It seems clear to me that this should work; the `selected` property of the object is set to true immediately before the call to `document.enterEditMode`. Tinkering with this function, I tried adding a line immediately after the `elementData.obj.selected = true;` line, tracing whether or not the selection was empty. The code looked like the following:

```
elementData.obj.selected = true;
fl.trace(fl.getDocumentDOM().selection.length);
```

The output of this code was `0`.

Why is this error occurring? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can only select symbol instances using document.selection. And you have to use fl.getDocumentDOM().selection = [array of symbol elements]